# Redirect wrong links Wordpress

Tags: htaccess, redirect

I am using the following permalinks structure: /%postname%/ and I also have some multi-page posts that look like /%postname%/2.

The problem is I see a lot of 404 errors in webmaster tools for urls like /post-name/random stuff here

How can I redirect all wrong URLs to the correct ones ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the Smart 404 plugin?
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/smart-404/

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a webserver to test this with, but the following should work:

In your wordpress theme, you can create a `404.php` file, which will be used when a 404 response is triggered. Inside this file, you could check the `HTTP_REFERRER` header entry - if it follows the format `/post-name/[nonsensical stuff]`, you could then redirect the browser to `/post-name/`. Or simply provide a link with a message saying "couldn't find exactly what you requested, but we think this might be it".